# JQuery datepicker calling method multiple times

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to work out, why when i select a date, both my methods get called twice?

```
 // Date Picker 

$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    orientation: "auto left",
    forceParse: false,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
}).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    oMessageDate.fnDraw();
    getMessageCount();
});
```

Both :

> oMessageDate and 
>   getMessageCount

are being called twice. these are Ajax webmethods using ASP.NET C#

Comment: can You provide a development link or something?!

Comment: Hi SSS - no, afraid not.

Comment: I think your functions are getting bind twice. Can check if its replicated or checked. Try to put up a alert or console on that change function

Comment: Have you called the provided code snipped twice? In this case you''l attach the changeDate event twice

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/susheel61/dHSQL/1/

i just see on test in console. its called only once

Comment: @susheel, this indeed, only writes to test once...putting my methods back in produces POSTS and GETS

Comment: Then you need to show your methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for change event

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker().change(function() {
      //your stuff
});
```

For Date Picker

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
  format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
  todayBtn: "linked",
  orientation: "auto left",
  forceParse: false,
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true
});
```

Comment: Alpesh, this now doubles the post to 4 per method call.

Comment: add your all code so that i can find the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I solved it as below. It worked for me!!!

```
var isHandled = false;

$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
todayBtn: "linked",
orientation: "auto left",
forceParse: false,
autoclose: true,
todayHighlight: true
}).on('changeDate', function(e) {
     if(!isHandled){
       e.preventDefault();
       oMessageDate.fnDraw();
       getMessageCount();
     }
  isHandled = true;
});
```